# Javascript for loop with asignment in comparison section

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Is this shortcut

```
var cars = [ "ford", "toyota"];

for (var i = 0, car; i < cars.length, car = cars[i]; i++) {
    console.log(car);
}
```

for

```
var cars = [ "ford", "toyota"];
var car;

for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    car = cars[i];

    console.log(car);
}
```

good or bad practice?

I have been using longer code notation for some time now, because the processed array name isn't always that short (cars), but now I tried to minimize it and found the solution.

Comment: I'd say it's bad, because it makes the code less clear. But isn't this question almost exclusively opinion-based?

Comment: @raina77ow yes, it's an opinion based question, and I've close-voted on that basis.  But anyone who thinks the former is good practise is wrong ;-)

Comment: In usually do `var car = cars[i];` inside the loop to make it look like block scoping.

Comment: I think that if you write var in for loop, this will allocate memory every time you run it, so if you repeat 1000 times, it will allocate memory 1000times, instead if you put it before the for loop, memory will be allocated only once.

Comment: @James07 no, that's wrong.  Firstly, the `var` actually gets hoisted out of the loop to the enclosing function scope.  Secondly, it's the _assignment_ that matters, not the declaration.  That's inside the loop, but all that happens is that various reference counts get updated - no new variables are being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already got solutions using `.forEach()`, here is solution with while loop:

```js
var cars = ["ford", "toyota"];
var car, i = 0;
while (car = cars[i++])
  console.log(car);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not  a good practice.

If you not wanna to access by using `index` try to use `forEach` instead

like this

```
var cars = [ "ford", "toyota"];

cars.forEach(function(car,index){
   console.log(car);
})
```

If wanna to use break then use [**some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [**every**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Try like this

**[SOME](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)**

```
var cars = [ "ford", "toyota"];

cars.some(function(car,index){
   console.log(car);
   return true; // break on return true
})
```

[**Every**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
var cars = [ "ford", "toyota"];

cars.every(function(car,index){
   console.log(car);
   return false; // break on return false
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rfqLmj2a/)

Comment: `.forEach` also exposes the array index, if you want it.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept it as an answer, but you can't break from it: http://jsfiddle.net/uteqrwzL/

Comment: this snipper forbids this functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/91ajjtn6/ (change i to 0, 1 and then 2.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this:

```
 cars.forEach(function(car, i) {
     ...
 });
```

since you've then got completely enclosed scope for the parameters `car` and `i`.